# Change font size in script editor window of standard GUI in R?

Tags: r

I can change font size of text in R console, but can I change it also for script editor window ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that if you open the script after you have changed the text size for the console window, then the text size has also changed for the editor. If you have opened the script and then try to change the text size, it only changes for the console window.
So, after opening R, change the text size first and then open the script.